# About the immutability of Python tuples

Tags: python, c++, tuples

I am trying to understand the concept of immutability in Python, as it applies to tuples. Consider the following code and its output:

```
A = ([1,2,3],['a','b','c'])
print id(A)
A[0].append(4)
A[1].append('d')
print id(A) # Prints the same id as the previous id(A) call even after contents are modified
```

Output: 140440567920328
140440567920328

As you can see, although the tuple retains the same identity, the contents have changed i.e. two lists, one of integers and one of doubles. I know similar questions have been discussed endlessly on Stack Overflow, but what I wanted to know if the following way of thinking about tuples is correct, if we are allowed to put a C++ angle on it.

Could the tuple in the above code be essentially considered as the
following struct, stripped of all the constructors, destructors 
and other methods as

```
 struct Python_Tuple_Cppform
 {
   vector<int>* const  viptr;
   vector<char>* const vcptr;
 }
```

Once the values of `viptr` and `vcptr` have been assigned by creating vectors somewhere in memory, their values cannot be changed. They are 
will permanently point to the same place in memory.

However, the contents of the vectors these pointers point to can most certainly be changed e.g. `(*viptr).push_back(4)` or `(*vcptr).push_back('d')`. This would explain the apparent 'paradox' 
of the Python code above. The tuple does not 'know' whether the contents
it has, are being changed or not.

And so, it is in this sense that the tuple is considered immutable, right?

**EDIT**

As suggested by murgatroid99 the ids of A[0] and A[1] before and after the 
append are the same.

```
A = ([1,2,3],['a','b','c'])
print id(A[0]), ' ' , id(A[1])
A[0].append(4)
A[1].append('d')
print id(A[0]), ' ' , id(A[1])
```

Output:

140485800073984   140485800079440

140485800073984   140485800079440

Comment: One way to test your theory would be to check `id(A[0])` and `id(A[1])` before and after the `append` calls.

Comment: lists are mutable any changes to them is not creating a new object so the tuple still holds the same pointers to the lists it did before. Only the list contents has changed. check the id's of both lists ad they will be the same no matter how many items you add or remove

Comment: @ murgatroid99 Yes, I tested it, they are the same before and after the append.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is correct.

Python objects are always referred to by pointer. The contents of a tuple cannot be mutated, but its contents are just pointers; you can still mutate the objects that these pointers point to, if those objects allow it.

As a commenter points out, one way to test your theory would be to check `id(A[0])` before and after the `append` calls. You would find that it remains the same.